# Weird Android Maps Extensions Run Time Issues

Tags: android, google-maps, runtime, android-maps-extensions

I downloaded a library called Android Maps Extensions from [Github](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions).

I can run the demo of this library in debugging mode, on my Samsung Note (GT-N7000) which runs Android 4.0.4.

If I click a button inside app, the app will stop and the screen will become black and after several seconds, and a dialog appears saying:

`Unfortunately, Android Maps Extensions has stopped.`

I am not sure what is happening. The logcat output can be seen below:

```
01-05 01:09:17.118: I/Process(24896): Sending signal. PID: 24896 SIG: 9
01-05 01:26:43.328: D/CLIPBOARD(27226): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
01-05 01:27:09.043: D/dalvikvm(27226): GC_CONCURRENT freed 56K, 2% free 14452K/14663K, paused 2ms+3ms
01-05 01:27:09.053: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27226): Certificate is not yet valid.
01-05 01:27:09.053: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27226): Google Play Store signature invalid.
01-05 01:27:09.053: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27226): Certificate is not yet valid.
01-05 01:27:09.053: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27226): Google Play Store signature invalid.
01-05 01:27:09.058: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27226): Certificate is not yet valid.
01-05 01:27:09.058: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27226): Google Play Store signature invalid.
01-05 01:27:09.058: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27226): Certificate is not yet valid.
01-05 01:27:09.058: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27226): Google Play Store signature invalid.
01-05 01:27:09.063: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27226): Certificate is not yet valid.
01-05 01:27:09.063: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27226): Google Play Store signature invalid.
01-05 01:27:09.078: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27226): Certificate is not yet valid.
01-05 01:27:09.078: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27226): Google Play Store signature invalid.
01-05 01:27:09.078: D/AndroidRuntime(27226): Shutting down VM
01-05 01:27:09.078: W/dalvikvm(27226): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c4f1f8)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.demo/pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.demo.DemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.demo.DemoActivity.addCircles(DemoActivity.java:220)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.demo.DemoActivity.onCreate(DemoActivity.java:84)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
01-05 01:27:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(27226):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug (`java.lang.NullPointerException`) - you should probably file a bug report on the Github site you got the code. Do you develop this code, or do you just want to use the Application? Please post what you tried to solve that problem!

Comment: @AlexanderVogt Yes, it's a bug in the demo. I should probably add checks for availability of Google Play services.